# XSLT transform with repeating elements and parent node

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I am trying to transform the below xml to rows and columns.
The `Job_Classification_Group` can have many child `Job_Classifications`. I need the `Job_Classification_Group_ID` to come first in all of the rows, then the information about that `Job_Classification_Group`, and then each `Job_Classification_Reference_ID`

In other words:

Job_Classification_Group_ID|wd:ID|wd:Effective_Date|wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name|wd:Location_Reference[2]|wd:Location_Reference[3]|wd:Location_Reference[4]|wd:Job_Classification_Data/Job_Classification_Reference_ID[1]
Job_Classification_Group_ID|wd:ID|wd:Effective_Date|wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name|wd:Location_Reference[2]|wd:Location_Reference[3]|wd:Location_Reference[4]|wd:Job_Classification_Data/Job_Classification_Reference_ID[2]

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Body>
      <wd:Get_Job_Classification_Groups_Response wd:version="v29.1" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
         <wd:Response_Filter>
            <wd:Page>3</wd:Page>
            <wd:Count>1</wd:Count>
         </wd:Response_Filter>
         <wd:Response_Group>
            <wd:Include_Reference>1</wd:Include_Reference>
            <wd:Include_Job_Classifications>1</wd:Include_Job_Classifications>
         </wd:Response_Group>
         <wd:Response_Results>
            <wd:Total_Results>21</wd:Total_Results>
            <wd:Total_Pages>21</wd:Total_Pages>
            <wd:Page_Results>1</wd:Page_Results>
            <wd:Page>3</wd:Page>
         </wd:Response_Results>
         <wd:Response_Data>
            <wd:Job_Classification_Group>
               <wd:Job_Classification_Group_Reference wd:Descriptor="Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)">
                  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">16d569ce573c01b6725820441e3b7049</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Group_ID">KldB2010_Germany</wd:ID>
               </wd:Job_Classification_Group_Reference>
               <wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name_Data>
                  <wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name>Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)</wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name>
               </wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name_Data>
               <wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data>
                  <wd:ID>KldB2010_Germany</wd:ID>
                  <wd:Effective_Date>2018-04-18-07:00</wd:Effective_Date>
                  <wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name>Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)</wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name>
                  <wd:Location_Reference wd:Descriptor="Germany">
                     <wd:ID wd:type="WID">dcc5b7608d8644b3a93716604e78e995</wd:ID>
                     <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">DE</wd:ID>
                     <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">DEU</wd:ID>
                     <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">276</wd:ID>
                  </wd:Location_Reference>
                  <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                  <wd:Job_Classification>
                     <wd:Job_Classification_Reference wd:Descriptor="1 - Land-, Forst- und Tierwirtschaft und Gartenbau (Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)-Germany)">
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">16d569ce573c0159e47b20441e3b7149</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Reference_ID">KldB2010_Germany_1_Land-,_Forst-_und_Tierwirtschaft_und_Gartenbau</wd:ID>
                     </wd:Job_Classification_Reference>
                     <wd:Job_Classification_Data>
                        <wd:ID>KldB2010_Germany_1_Land-,_Forst-_und_Tierwirtschaft_und_Gartenbau</wd:ID>
                        <wd:Job_Classification_ID>1</wd:Job_Classification_ID>
                        <wd:Description>Land-, Forst- und Tierwirtschaft und Gartenbau</wd:Description>
                        <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                     </wd:Job_Classification_Data>
                  </wd:Job_Classification>
                  <wd:Job_Classification>
                     <wd:Job_Classification_Reference wd:Descriptor="11 - Land-, Tier- und Forstwirtschaftsberufe (Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)-Germany)">
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">16d569ce573c016e488520441e3b7249</wd:ID>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Reference_ID">KldB2010_Germany_11_Land-,_Tier-_und_Forstwirtschaftsberufe</wd:ID>
                     </wd:Job_Classification_Reference>
                     <wd:Job_Classification_Data>
                        <wd:ID>KldB2010_Germany_11_Land-,_Tier-_und_Forstwirtschaftsberufe</wd:ID>
                        <wd:Job_Classification_ID>11</wd:Job_Classification_ID>
                        <wd:Description>Land-, Tier- und Forstwirtschaftsberufe</wd:Description>
                        <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
                     </wd:Job_Classification_Data>
                  </wd:Job_Classification>
               </wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data>
            </wd:Job_Classification_Group>
         </wd:Response_Data>
      </wd:Get_Job_Classification_Groups_Response>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I have a simple XSLT to build this without the `Job_Classification_Reference_ID`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newline">
        <xsl:text>&#166;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="comma">
        <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="quote">
        <xsl:text>&#39;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="rs">
        <xsl:text>&#124;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Job_Classification_Groups_Response/wd:Response_Data"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Job_Classification_Groups_Response/wd:Response_Data">
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:Job_Classification/wd:Job_Classification_Reference/wd:ID[2]">
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../wd:ID"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../wd:Effective_Date"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../wd:Inactive"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../wd:Location_Reference/wd:ID[2]"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../wd:Location_Reference/wd:ID[3]"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../wd:Location_Reference/wd:ID[4]"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which outputs:

```
KldB2010_Germany|2018-04-18-07:00|Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)|0|DE|DEU|276|KldB2010_Germany_1_Land-,_Forst-_und_Tierwirtschaft_und_Gartenbau¦KldB2010_Germany|2018-04-18-07:00|Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)|0|DE|DEU|276|KldB2010_Germany_11_Land-,_Tier-_und_Forstwirtschaftsberufe
```

Which is close, but does not have `Job_Classification_Group_ID`

I cannot figure out how to keep the repeating `Job_Classification_Reference_ID` while also adding the `Job_Classification_Group_ID`. I tried creating another template which was called from inside the loop but got an error (Using XMLSpy). That template would just output the `Job_Classification_Reference_ID` value.

EDIT: Expected output

```
KldB2010_Germany|KldB2010_Germany|2018-04-18-07:00|Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)|0|DE|DEU|276|KldB2010_Germany_1_Land-,_Forst-_und_Tierwirtschaft_und_Gartenbau¦
KldB2010_Germany|KldB2010_Germany|2018-04-18-07:00|Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)|0|DE|DEU|276|KldB2010_Germany_11_Land-,_Tier-_und_Forstwirtschaftsberufe
```

But the first column is `Job_Classification_Group_ID` from `wd:Job_Classification_Group_Reference`. Not `wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data`. That is the 2nd column

Comment: Can you share the desired output based on the input XML? Looking at the `<xsl:for-each>`, it is going to output a single row since the context will always be `<wd:ID[2]>` for the specified XPath.

Comment: @AniketV updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of suggestions to achieve the desired output. The requirement is to get the value of

```
<xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Classification_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Job_Classification_Reference_ID']"/>
```

on separate rows in the output text. In order to do it the `<xsl:for-each>` should run on `<wd:Job_Classification>` instead of `wd:Job_Classification/wd:Job_Classification_Reference/wd:ID[2]`.

Secondly, in this particular scenario, instead of using `../../../` to go up levels for accessing parent node values, a better way is to use `ancestor::` axis which will help in easily creating the XPath and navigating to the required node. It also helps in understanding which element value is being accessed by just looking at the XSLT code.

Thirdly, instead of accessing values using `wd:ID[2]`, `wd:ID[3]`, `wd:ID[4]` it would be good to access them using the `@wd:type` attribute value i.e. `wd:ID[@wd:type='ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code']` and so on for the others. This will ensure the output does not change even if the sequence of the `wd:ID` elements in the input change.

Based on the above suggestions the `wd:ResponseData` template is modified as below.

```
<xsl:template match="/env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Job_Classification_Groups_Response/wd:Response_Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:Job_Classification">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Job_Classification_Group_ID']" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:ID" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:Effective_Date"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:Inactive"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:Location_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code']"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:Location_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code']"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:Job_Classification_Group_Data/wd:Location_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code']"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$rs"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Classification_Reference/wd:ID[@wd:type='Job_Classification_Reference_ID']"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This will generate the required output

```
KldB2010_Germany|KldB2010_Germany|2018-04-18-07:00|Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)|0|DE|DEU|276|KldB2010_Germany_1_Land-,_Forst-_und_Tierwirtschaft_und_Gartenbau¦
KldB2010_Germany|KldB2010_Germany|2018-04-18-07:00|Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)|0|DE|DEU|276|KldB2010_Germany_11_Land-,_Tier-_und_Forstwirtschaftsberufe
```

Comment: Ah. I was looking at the axis option but couldn't quite make the connection. This makes a lot of sense, and point taken on specifying the attribute value.